# how to combine Isin , contains ,with case sensitive while filtering data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame and I have multiple conditions to filter that data 
for ex:

```
state =  Andhra Pradesh, Uttar Pradesh, Madya Pradesh, Karnataka, Telangana
```

and

```
field_id = 23234,23235,34342,34343...

 Input: 
 --------
field_id,state,latitude,longitude
23234,Uttar Pradesh,28.05990445,78.34249247
23235,Uttar Pradesh,27.6206712,78.7132515
23236,Uttar Pradesh,27.95378227,79.04653615
23237,Uttar Pradesh,28.63232205,78.5763061
34342,Telangana,18.71517059,78.70715893
34343,Telangana,18.11666882,79.3873906
34344,Telangana,18.4527501,79.21027678
45452,Madhya Pradesh,21.70770808,75.67139279
45453,Madhya Pradesh,21.75613982,76.29656126
45454,Madhya Pradesh,22.05077277,79.2375098
56562,Karnataka,12.38318394,76.02965431
56563,Karnataka,12.38297092,76.02957524
56564,Karnataka,14.26369026,75.43180631
67672,Andhra Pradesh,16.83612945,80.99260486
67673,Andhra Pradesh,16.83277887,80.99537748
67674,Andhra Pradesh,16.83311322,80.99560818
```

I tried

```
state = Andhra Pradesh,Madhya Pradesh,Karnataka
State1 = State.split(',')
dsna = dsna.loc[dsna['State'].isin(State1)]
```

Which works with exact match case

```
field_id = 23234,34345
field_id1 = field_id.split(',')
dsna = dsna.loc[dsna['field_id'].isin(field_id1)]
```

Here also filters exact data frame

here dsna is my dataframe i will attach csv of that data frame or table

```
dsna = dsna.loc[dsna['field_id'].isin(field_id1)]
dsna = dsna.loc[dsna['State'].isin(State1)]
```

I wanted filter data based on regex format 
like state = pradesh,telangana ( i gave lower case) 
it should filter all data related to those states and list down latitude and longitude 
similar way `field_id= 232,343,454` should filter all fields reated to data expecting data should relate to the regex and case sensitive and filter multiple values any pandas functionality helps to do that Since my data already in data frame

Answer (score 0):

By using Pandas

```
dsna = dsna[dsna['State'].str.contains('|'.join(State),
                                                     case=False)]
```

I used `|` to search throughout Strings.